# Should Prius brake pedal feel firmer after replacing brake pads?

Tags: brakes, brake-fluid, prius

2013 Prius Plug-in

I just replaced the front brake pads and rotors.  On other cars I've owned, the brake pedal feels firmer after replacing pads.  This one does not; there is lots of travel on the pedal without pushing hard.

The Prius brake system is a little different that a pure gasoline car.  Does that explain the lack of firmer feeling?  Is this a possible sign of air in the system?

Comment: The shop should have bled the brakes after replacing the pads. Not all shops will do that (nor will all home mechanics). You might consider asking the shop if they did so, and if not schedule an appointment to have them finish the job.